# How to show a preview for web url contents when web address is typed in Textbox using Swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, validation, social-networking

**Scenario:**

Creating a social network app type application, when user type the web address or valid url in the text area my app should identify the valid url,then I have to do the following tasks,

1) If it is a valid web url then automatically show the preview of the web contents in the preview section.

2) Share button should not be enabled until the preview is fully loaded, if not there are some chances that URL alone may be posted instead of the web contents.

**What I have tried?**

Created a Text view and a preview WebUI view, I used following code to identify the valid URL, if valid url then I am showing the web view and loading the web page.

**Code what I tried:**

```
class CommentsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var comments: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var preview: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnShare: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        preview.isHidden = true
        btnShare.isEnabled = false
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    @IBAction func valueModified(_ sender: Any) {
        //Load web preview only after Check for Valid Web URL
        if  verifyUrl(urlString: comments.text) == true {
            preview.isHidden = false
            preview.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: comments.text!)!))
            btnShare.isEnabled = true

        }
    }

    //Check for Valid Web URL
    func verifyUrl (urlString: String?) -> Bool {
        //Check for nil
        if let urlString = urlString {
            // create NSURL instance
            if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
                // check if your application can open the NSURL instance
                return UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url as URL)
            }
        }
        return false
    }

}
```

**What I need exactly?**

I do not want to load the web page, I have to load the preview of the page.
Share button should be hidden until the preview is fully loaded.

**Screen shot of my code output:**

[image]

**Screen shot of what I am expecting:**

[image]

Comment: You would want to pull the data for your preview view from the webpages open graph meta-tags.

Comment: I actually want to show the preview of URL , say for example, when you share a you tube URL the Thumbnail image will be displayed in the preview. When you paste any web site, the logo or some image in the website will be loaded and shown in preview.

Comment: I understand that.  The url to the thumbnail, the title, the description, etc. that are meant to be shown in the preview are in the page's open graph tags.

Comment: @dan Thanks for update, just to summarize, I have to use Open graph tag controls to implement this feature in my mobile app. Do I need to add the UIKIT or its existing feature, I am new to IOS development not sure to add.

Comment: @dan Found the open graph is for Facebook related posting or I can use for my own application, I am trying to create my own social post application in web and mobile.

Comment: Please refrain from posting additional content in comments. Rather, edit your question. StackOverflow isn't designed to be a discussion forum.

Comment: Many webpages don't have open graph meta-tags for images (like Amazon). That is a web preview like this would be useful. @IpsitaSethi what did you end up doing?